# Can I make firebug ajax console show who called jQuery?

Tags: jquery, firebug

One of the really useful features in Firebug is the ajax requests showing up right in the debug console. In addition to the request and response content, it also shows which line called the XMLHttpRequest.send, which could be very useful.

The problem is, since I'm using jQuery, it always shows the same place - "jQuery-1.7.js (line 8155)". Is there any trick, option, or extension I can use to make it show who called jQuery in each case?

I have FireQuery installed. It's great, but doesn't solve this specific issue.

**UPDATE**: So, looking at the FireBug source code ([requestStarted](https://github.com/johan/firebug/blob/master/content/firebug/spy.js#L356), [getStackSourceLink](https://github.com/johan/firebug/blob/master/content/firebug/lib.js#L1512)), it seems that it's not really possible to do this with an extension or an option, though it wouldn't be hard to make this change in FireBug itself. When I have more time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need access to the call stack, but I don't know if Firebug actually stores that for AJAX requests.

The only thing I can think of is to use the non-compressed version of jQuery and place a breakpoint on the AJAX line and check the call stack when the script stops there.